# Documentation with Doxia + Ant

Tags: documentation, ant, doxia

I would like to use [Doxia](http://maven.apache.org/doxia) to generate some documentation but invoke it with Ant (and no, Maven is not an option).  I was looking for some pointers but nothing popped up after a few Google search.

Did anyone already used Doxia in an Ant environment and how did it turned out?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of any Ant Doxia task, it really would be simpler to use Maven or the invoke [Mvn ant task](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/examples/mvn.html) from within your Ant build to invoke Doxia...

If this is really not feasible, it should be fairly straightforward to cobble together a [custom ant task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/develop.html) to invoke Doxia.

As requested, some pointers to get started:

Maven is based on [Plexus](http://plexus.codehaus.org/) and the Doxia components are available from the Plexus container to an application.
There is a tutorial on [getting started with Plexus](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/05/plexus-container-five-minute-tutorial/) you might find helpful for some background on creating a wrapper.

The example below shows how you can obtain the [SiteTools](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-doxia-tools/usage.html) component in a standalone application. As in the Ant tutorial referenced above, it would be straightforward to wrap the execution in an Ant task.

```
public class DoxiaPlexusTest
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
        throws Exception {
        // create a new container
        PlexusContainer container = new DefaultPlexusContainer();

        SiteTool siteTool = container.lookup( SiteTool.class );

        try {
            new DoxiaPlexusTest().letsDoDoxia(siteTool);
        finally {
            // stop the components and container
            container.dispose();
        }
    }

    public void letsDoDoxia(SiteTool siteTool) {
        List localesList = siteTool.getAvailableLocales( locales );
        String relativePath = siteTool.getRelativePath( "C:/foo/child",
                            "C:/foo/master" );
        ...
    }
}
```